# Angular 2 Http.Post don't pass data

Tags: http, post, angular

I have problem with passing data by Http.Post. I get an error 405 (Method Not Allowed)which mean there is no method in API. This is true, when I removed arguments from Post method everything works fine.

Angular 2 Service Code:

```
SaveChoice(QuestionId:number, ItemId:number):Observable<boolean>{
    let body = JSON.stringify({ QuestionId,ItemId });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


    return this._http.post('http://localhost:42055/api/Question',body,options)
            .map((response:Response) => <boolean>response.json());
}
```

I use .subscribe() i main TS file.

.Net Web API code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(int QuestionId, int ItemId)
    {
        return _statisticsService.AddNewRecord(QuestionId,ItemId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would see several things to check:

- **The path of your resource**. Is it the right one and does it correspond to your `Post` method?
- I think that that your **method input** isn't correct since you will receive something like that:

  ```
  { "QuestionId": "some question id", "ItemId": "some item id" }
  ```

  So you should use a class as methoid parameter containing these two properties.

I think that in your case, the problem comes from the second option. Your server can't map the received payload to your input parameters. So it will return a 405 error code.

Comment: I tried 
let body = JSON.stringify({ 
           "QuestionId":QuestionId,
           "ItemId":ItemId 
        });

But it is still not working. But when I look into debug , JSON do it automatically

Comment: It's actually the same ;-)

Comment: I think that you should have something like that on the server side: `[HttpPost]
    public bool Post(Models.QuestionItem questionItem)`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891804/can-i-pass-an-object-from-angular2-to-an-mvc5-post/36891916#36891916

Comment: Problem is that, this data us not send. There is no problem with mapping.
When I looking into Fiddler there is no sign of data.

Comment: Do you include the `Headers` class: `import {Http, Headers, ... } from 'angular2/http';`?

Comment: import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http,Response,Headers,RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';   I take this

Comment: Seems correct. When you say "this data us not send", you mean that you receive an empty request on the server side?

Comment: Request was send but there is no data inside, so there is no body

Answer (score 0):

Okey problem was in Server Side.
I was sending an object so Server also expect and object not the two separated values.

So if we change Server side to :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Post(test data)
    {
       return _statisticsService.AddNewRecord(data.QuestionId,data.ItemId);
    }
```

Where class test is:

```
public class test
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}
```

Eveerything works fine...